# Training HMM - The amount of data required

Tags: matlab, validation, computer-vision, hidden-markov-models

I'm using HMM for classifications. I came cross an example in Wikipedia [Baum–Welch algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baum%E2%80%93Welch_algorithm) Example. Hope someone can help me.

The example as follow: "Suppose we have a chicken from which we collect eggs at noon everyday. Now whether or not the chicken has laid eggs for collection depends on some unknown factors that are hidden. We can however (for simplicity) assume that there are only two states that determine whether the chicken lays eggs."

Note that we have 2 different observations (N and E) and 2 states (S1 and S2) in this example.

My question here is:

How many observations/Observed sequences (or training data) do we need to best train the model. Is there any way to estimate or to test the amount of training data required.

Answer (score 1):

For each variable in your HMM model, you need about 10 samples. Using this rule of thumb, you can easily calculate how many samples do you need to construct a reliable classifier.
In your example you have two states which results in a 2 in 2 transition matrix A=[a_00, a_01;a_10, a_11] where a_ij is the transition probability from state S_i to S_j.

Moreover, each of these states with probability p_S1 and p_S2 generate observations, i.e.: If we are at state S1 with probability p_S1 the chicken will lay egg and with probability 1-p_S1 it will not. 
In total you have 6 variables needed to be estimate. It is more or less obvious that it is not possible to accurately estimate them from only two observations. As I mentioned before, it is conventional to assume at least 10 samples per variable are needed in order to estimate that variable accurately.

Comment: Why 10 sample? based one what you give this number?

Comment: Provide more details.  This is borderline comment territory.